# Recommended Python Modules for Function Argument Handling?

Tags: python, parsing, arguments

There are many Python modules for parsing and coordinating command line options (argparse, getopt, blargs, etc). And Python is blessed with good built-in features/idioms for handling varied function arguments (e.g., default values, *varargs, **keyword_args). But when I read various projects' code for top-level functions, I see notably less discipline and standardization of function arguments than command line arguments.

For simple functions, this isn't an issue; the built-in argument features work great and are more than sufficient. But there are a lot of functionally rich modules whose top-level functions provide lots of different arguments and options (some complementary or exclusive), different modes of operation, defaults, over-rides, etc.--that is, they have argument complexity approaching that of command line arguments. And they seem to largely handle their arguments in *ad hoc* ways.

Given the number of command line processing modules out there, and how refined they've become over time, I'd expect at least a few modules for simplifying the wrangling of complicated function arguments. But I've searched PyPi, stackoverflow, and Google without success. So...are there function (not command line!) argument handling modules you would recommend?

---update with example---

It's hard to give a truly simple concrete example because the use case doesn't appear until you're dealing with a sophisticated module. But here's a shot at explaining the problem in code: A formatter module with defaults that can be overridden in formatter instantiation, or when the function/method is called. For having only a few options, there's already an awful lot of option-handling verbiage, and the option names are repeated *ad nauseam*.

```
defaults = { 'indent':     4,
              'prefix':    None,
              'suffix':    None,
              'name':      'aFormatter',
              'reverse':   False,
              'show_name': False
            }

class Formatter(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name    = kwargs.get('name',    defaults['name'])
        self.indent  = kwargs.get('indent',  defaults['indent'])
        self.prefix  = kwargs.get('prefix',  defaults['prefix'])
        self.suffix  = kwargs.get('suffix',  defaults['suffix'])
        self.reverse = kwargs.get('reverse', defaults['reverse'])
        self.show_name = kwargs.get('show_name', defaults['show_name'])

    def show_lower(self, *args, **kwargs):
        indent = kwargs.get('indent', self.indent) or 0
        prefix = kwargs.get('prefix', self.prefix) 
        suffix = kwargs.get('suffix', self.suffix)
        reverse = kwargs.get('reverse', self.reverse)
        show_name = kwargs.get('show_name', self.show_name)

        strings = []
        if show_name:
            strings.append(self.name + ": ")
        if indent:
            strings.append(" " * indent)
        if prefix:
            strings.append(prefix)
        for a in args:
            strings.append(a.upper() if reverse else a.lower())
        if suffix:
            strings.append(suffix)
        print ''.join(strings)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fmt = Formatter()
    fmt.show_lower("THIS IS GOOD")
    fmt.show_lower("THIS", "IS", "GOOD")
    fmt.show_lower('this IS good', reverse=True)
    fmt.show_lower("something!", show_name=True)

    upper = Formatter(reverse=True)
    upper.show_lower("this is good!")
    upper.show_lower("and so is this!", reverse=False)
```

Comment: are you talking about def somefunc(requiredValue, optionalValue=None, *args, **kwargs)? If so code that into your function, just like you would handle command line args coming from a terminal (which is a function itself).

Comment: Could you give an example of a function with a complex interface, and an idea of what simplifications you'd expect from a library?  (For what it's worth, I think there are some Python modules out there with rather terrible function interfaces.  I'd recommend to consider them as deterrent examples rather than trying to do something like this yourself.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach There are indeed extremely cautionary, avoid-at-all-costs examples out there! But when a function (say a factory function) is the entry point for a sophisticated capability, that it's complex isn't necessarily an error. It may simply reflect the complexity/variability of the job at hand.

Comment: Still, an example of such an interface would be nice.  Currently, the discussion is way too abstract to lead anywhere.  Let's discuss code.

Comment: @platinummonkey: No. Your example correctly states Python's built-in argument features. What I'm talking about is the next level: situations where, e.g., if mode=="cartesian" the routine needs x and y, but if mode=="polar" it needs radius and angle (and if it gets x or y, it'd be nice to print an error message). I know it's sometimes possible to refactor an API into several distinct, simpler sub-cases. I do that whenever practical. Here, I'm asking for modules that help when refactoring is not possible--when a single function is the natural entry point.

Comment: [_ad nauseam_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_nauseam) is right :)

Comment: What kind of API would you like to see for such a module?

Answer (score 3):

When I first read your question, I thought to myself that you're asking for a band-aid module, and that it doesn't exist because nobody wants to write a module that enables bad design to persist.

But I realized that the situation is more complex than that. The point of creating a module such as the one you describe is to create reusable, general-case code. Now, it may well be that there are some interfaces that are justifiably complex. But those interfaces are *precisely* the interfaces that probably can't be handled easily by general-case code. They are complex because they address a problem domain with a lot of special cases.

In other words, if an interface *really can't* be refactored, then it probably requires a lot of custom, special-case code that isn't predictable enough to be worth generalizing in a module. Conversely, if an interface can easily be patched up with a module of the kind you describe, then it probably can also be refactored -- in which case it should be.

Comment: Disagree. Following this argument, it wouldn't make sense to generalize command line processing into argparse, getopt, etc. But it does. What I'm asking is the analog for modules and functions: code that generalizes and simplifies complex functions--when appropriate, and sometimes it is!--in the same way argparse helps for commands. My reading of code on PyPi suggests simplifying this use would be helpful. And it isn't impossible--I have a good working solution. Just looking to see if there are more accepted avenues. With so many "just refactor!" answers, I'm guessing there isn't. Yet.

Comment: @JonathanEunice, well, I never said it was impossible. I just said it's likely to increase, rather than decrease, the complexity of justifiably-complex codebases. More generally, I think the analogy between command line interfaces and APIs is a false one. They really aren't so similar.

Comment: IMO a difference of degree, not kind. Command lines and functions each invoke some functionality, with a given set of options, instructions, and data. Happily, functions are often simpler and more refactorable. But code I've seen from PyPi suggests there's still a need to simplify functions. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't think command line parsing and function argument processing have much in common.  The main issue with the command line is that the only available data structure is a flat list of strings, and you don't have an instrument like a function header available to define what each string means.  In the header of a Python function, you can give names to each of the parameters, you can accept containers as parameters, you can define default argument values etc.  What a command line parsing library does is actually providing for the command line some of the features Python offers for function calls: give names to parameters, assign default values, convert to the desired types etc.  In Python, all these features are built-in, so you don't need a library to get to that level of convenience.
2. Regarding your example, there are numerous ways how this design can be improved by using the features the language offers.  You can use default argument values instead of your `defaults` dictionary, you can encapsulate all the flags in a `FormatterConfig` class and only pass one argument instead of all those arguments again and again.  But let's just assume you want exactly the interface you gave in the example code.  One way to achieve this would be the following code:

   ```
   class Config(dict):
       def __init__(self, config):
           dict.__init__(self, config)
           self.__dict__ = self

   def get_config(kwargs, defaults):
       config = defaults.copy()
       config.update(kwargs)
       return Config(config)

   class Formatter(object):

       def __init__(self, **kwargs):
           self.config = get_config(kwargs, defaults)

       def show_lower(self, *args, **kwargs):
           config = get_config(kwargs, self.config)

           strings = []
           if config.show_name:
               strings.append(config.name + ": ")
           strings.append(" " * config.indent)
           if config.prefix:
               strings.append(config.prefix)
           for a in args:
               strings.append(a.upper() if config.reverse else a.lower())
           if config.suffix:
               strings.append(config.suffix)
           print "".join(strings)
   ```

   Python offers a lot of tools to do this kind of argument handling.  So even if we decide not to use some of them (like default arguments), we still can avoid to repeat ourselves too much.

Comment: Point 1: Yes! Nicely put. Python functions start much richer than the flat strings of command line arguments. 

Point 2: Concur. If Config/get_config were in a module, it'd be a good start on exactly what I was asking for...clean out-of-the-box handling of configuration defaults, overrides, etc. that extends Python args to suit/support highly-optioned functions. Surprised there isn't a polished, well-known module on PyPi for this already.

Answer (score 1):

If your API is so complex you think it would be easier to use some module to process the options that were passed you, there's a good chance the *actual* solution is to simplify your API. The fact some modules have very complex ways to call stuff is a shame, not a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Its in developer's hand, but if you're making a library which may be useful for some other projects or will be published across other users, then I think first you need to identify your problem and analyse it,

Document your functions well, Its good to minimize the number of arguments,
provide default values for functional arguments where users may have trouble to specify what exactly needed to pass.

and for some complex requirement you can provide special `classmethods` that can be override for advanced programming or by advanced users who actually wants to achieve what they are playing with the library, inheritance is always there.

and you can read the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) also which may helpful, but ultimate goal is to specify the minimum number of arguments, restrict users to enter required arguments, its good to provide default values for optional arguments - in the way that your `library` / `code` is easily understandable by ordinary developers too...

Answer (score 0):

You could write more generic code for the defaulting.

If you think about defaulting the other way around, going through the defaults and overwriting the keywords if the don't exist.

```
 defaults = { 'indent':     4,
          'prefix':    None,
          'suffix':    None,
          'name':      'aFormatter',
          'reverse':   False,
          'show_name': False
        }

class Formatter(object):

   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      for d,dv in defaults.iteritems():
         kwargs[d] = kwargs.get(d, dv)
```

Side Note:
I'd recommend using keywords args in the `__init__` method definition with defaults. This allows the `function` definition really become the contract to other developers and users of your class (`Formatter`)

```
def __init__(self, indent=4, reverse=False .....etc..... ):
```

Comment: `kwargs[d] = kwargs.get(d, dv)` can be written as `kwargs.setdefault(d, dv)`.  That's why it's called `setdefault()` -- it set's a default value if no value has been set yet.